# this.getJobStore is not a function - extjs

Tags: extjs, extjs4

1) I have a store called "Job". Is correct that method "getJobStore" is automatically created.

2) in the following code example. I get this error. "this.getJobStore is not a function". When i go console.info(this) i do not see this function. So what property should be "this" ?

```
    onSubmitBtnClick: function () {

    var form = Ext.getCmp('formJobSummary');
    var record = form.getRecord();
    var values = form.getValues();
    this.getJobStore().sync();


},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you have set the scope properly for your `onSubmitBtnClick` listener.  My guess is that it is running in the scope of your button, not your controller (that is, you haven't specified `scope: this` in your listener configuration).  If you post the configuration of the controller entirely, we would be able to say for sure.

Answer (score 1):

`this` should be a controller object which is listening the events of this button (as example).
Is that true for you now?